# How to divide three <div> vertically in a 20:50:30 ratio using flexbox with full height of screen?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I want to make a **mobile first** responsive layout using flex where three sections are divided vertically in 20:50:30 ratio with full height of screen.

This the HTML part:

```
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="topSection">
        This is Top Section
      </div>
      <div class="middleSection">
        This is Middle Section
      </div>
      <div class="bottomSection">
        This is Bottom Section
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Expected Layout:

[image: Vertically divided sections using flexbox]

Comment: What do you want to happen on viewports that don't have enough height/width to accommodate all of all the sections? (ie which should scroll first and/or are there minimima which should be set?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `height: 100vh` to make the parent 100% of the "view height". Set `display: flex` on your parent and set the `flex-direction: column`.

Then you can use the `flex` option on the children to give them the relative  size you want.

The whole css should look something like this:

```
.parent {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.topSection {
    flex: 2;
}

.middleSection {
    flex: 5;
}

.bottomSection {
    flex:3;
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. Have a great day

Answer (score 1):

i'm new here, hope this answer can helps you :D

- `display: flex`｜Set the layout into flex
- `flex-direction: column`｜Set the direction of flex into column
- `height: 100vh`｜Set the height of outter div into 100% of page height
- `flex: <value>`｜Set the proportion of div

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100vh">
  <div style="flex:20%">
    This is Top Section
  </div>
  <div style="flex:50%">
    This is Middle Section
  </div>
  <div style="flex:30%">
    This is Bottom Section
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.topSection {
  flex: 20%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.middleSection {
  flex: 50%;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

.bottomSection {
  flex: 30%;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="topSection">
        This is Top Section
      </div>
      <div class="middleSection">
        This is Middle Section
      </div>
      <div class="bottomSection">
        This is Bottom Section
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
}

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.topSection {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}

.middleSection {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}

.bottomSection {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="topSection">
        This is Top Section
      </div>
      <div class="middleSection">
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
        <div>This is Middle Section</div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomSection">
        This is Bottom Section
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are looking for mobile first responsive layout here is the updated code for you. Feel free to resize your window.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="topSection">
        This is Top Section
      </div>
      <div class="middleSection">
        This is Middle Section
      </div>
      <div class "bottomSection">
        This is Bottom Section
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex: 1;
}

.topSection {
    background-color: #ff5733;
    flex: 20%;
}

.middleSection {
    background-color: #33ff57;
    flex: 50%;
}

.bottomSection {
    background-color: #5733ff;
    flex: 30%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .parent {
    flex-direction: column;
   }
    
}
```